# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, ios, serialization, nullpointerexception

This is the error i get:

> 03-11 08:27:48.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23647): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.plan.yeahimin/com.plan.yeahimin.PlanDetailsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

I understand its due to a variable having a null value but I can't workout why. It looks like it's 'EXTRA_NEW_PLAN' in the `getSerializable()` method in the `DetailsFragment` but other than that I don't know. I'm new to Android so forgive me if it's obvious but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code for the `ListFragment`;

```
public class PlanListFragment extends ListFragment {

public final static String TAG = "com.plan.yeahimin.PlanListFragment";
public final static String EXTRA_NEW_PLAN = "com.plan.yeahimin.plan_id";

private Button mAddPlan;
private ArrayList<Plan> mPlansList;


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_view_or_list_view, parent, false);
    ListView view = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    view.setEmptyView(v.findViewById(android.R.id.empty));

    mAddPlan = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.add_a_plan);

    mAddPlan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "add plan clicked");
            Plan plan = new Plan();
            Log.d(TAG, "new plan created");
            PlanArrayList.get(getActivity()).addPlans(plan);
            Log.d(TAG, "plan added to mPlansList");
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PlanDetailsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(PlanDetailsFragment.EXTRA_NEW_PLAN, plan.getId());
            startActivity(i);
            return;
        }

    });
    return v;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    mPlansList = PlanArrayList.get(getActivity()).getPlans();
    //ArrayList<Plan> mPlansList = new ArrayList<Plan>();
    PlanArrayAdapter paa = new PlanArrayAdapter(mPlansList);
    setListAdapter(paa);

}

public class PlanArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Plan>{


    public PlanArrayAdapter(ArrayList<Plan> planList){ 
        super(getActivity(), 0, planList);

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    // Get the plan item for this position
    Plan plan = getItem(position);

    //If layout doesnt exist, inflate one
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.plan_list_fragment, parent, false);

    }

    TextView planTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plan_title);
    planTitle.setText(plan.getTitle());
    TextView planDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plan_date);
    planDate.setText(plan.getDate().toString());

        return convertView;
    }

}

}
```

and here is my code for the DetailsFragment which opens from add button;

```
public class PlanDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "com.plan.yeahimin.PlanDetailsFragment";
public static final String EXTRA_NEW_PLAN = "com.plan.yeahimin.plan_id";

private EditText mTitleField;
private Button mDateButton;
private Button mTimeButton;
private EditText mLocationField;
private EditText mAttendeesField;
private EditText mDescriptionField;
private Plan mPlan;
private ArrayList<Plan> mPlansList;

public static PlanDetailsFragment newInstance(UUID planId){


    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(EXTRA_NEW_PLAN, planId);
    PlanDetailsFragment f = new PlanDetailsFragment();
    f.setArguments(args);
    Log.d(TAG, "newInstance created");
    return f;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    UUID planId = (UUID)getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_NEW_PLAN);
    mPlan = PlanArrayList.get(getActivity()).getPlan(planId);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.plan_details_fragment, parent, false);

    mTitleField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.plan_title);

    mLocationField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.plan_location);
    mAttendeesField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.plan_attendees);
    mDescriptionField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.plan_description);
    mDateButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.plan_date);
    mTimeButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.plan_time);


    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_to_do, menu);

}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){

    case R.id.save_button:

        Log.d(TAG, "save button pressed");
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Problem with args.putSerializable(EXTRA_NEW_PLAN, planId); Why you using UUID , also show where you calling newInstance(UUID)

Comment: your issue is in `PlanDetailsActivity`. Would you mind posting it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot send any arguments to your Fragment with .newInstance(), because this method does not accept any parameters according to the documentation. So even if you have overloaded .newInstance(UUID), the system calls .newInstance() (if calls at all, I have some doubts). Also please be aware that you put the parameter to Intent with .putExtra(), but do not recall it from the Intent.

In fact the right way to send arguments to a Fragment is as follows:

In the caller (usually it is an Activity, but maybe with another Fragment, like in your example, it would also work, I cannot say for sure):

```
PlanDetailsFragment fragment = new PlanDetailsFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable(PlanDetailsFragment.TAG_NEW_PLAN, plan.getID());
fragment.setArguments(args);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fragment, TAG_DETAILS_FRAGMENT).commit();
```

In the fragment:

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
UUID planID = (UUID) args.getSerializable(TAG_NEW_PLAN);
```

It is not a ready-to-use code, you should adapt it to your classes and variables names, to where your tags are places, etc. The calls of Activity methods may also require some change if you prefer to work from another fragment. It is just an overall description.

My answer applies to the situation when both fragments are inside one activity. Your using of Intents make me have doubts in this, but I do not fully understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You sent the arguments to an Activity(PlanDetailsActivity).

You should send the arguments to a Fragment through newInstance() method.

In your PlainDetailsActivity, you should create the fragment instance like:

```
UUID uuid = getIntent().getSerializableExtra(PlanDetailsFragment.EXTRA_NEW_PLAN);
PlanDetailsFragment f = PlanDetailsFragment.newInstance(uuid);
```